# Could a planet be cut in half and still sustain life?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, life

Say some sort of anti-planet weapon shoots an arc of energy slicing the planet in 2, could the said planet keep it’s atmosphere and life.

Comment: Are the halves separated at all? How does the slicing happen? A narrow beam passed slowly through the planet might seal itself up almost immediately, like how a wire with heavy weights hanging from it can be passed through a block of ice without actually cutting it in half. But since this is an "anti-planet weapon", I imagine it's designed to be pretty catastrophic.

Comment: Also, anything that imparts escape velocity on the two halves would kill everything.

Comment: Ah there's one of these popular questions.. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=planet+cut+half Tip to prevent closure: tell us more about the weapon, e.g.  is this "arc of energy" infinitely thin ? How fast does this "arc of energy" travel ?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Your question is good, of course, but I'm trying to imagine anything that could deliver enough energy to slice a planet in half that wouldn't also be pretty catastrophic just on that count. It's heating solid matter up enough that it disintegrates... it'd be like try to slice bread with a blow torch wouldn't it?

Comment: Not enough information to answer.  If you could slice the planet in two with a thin enough cut,  you wouldn't even notice it. The planet woild simply be pulled back together again by gravity.  If the cut was a mile wide you will get a very different answer.   If a miracle transporter simply removed half of the planet leaving only one bowl-shaped half,  it would slowly collapse into a half-sized sphere,  and the energy released would melt everything.

Comment: VTC requiring more detail.

Comment: This is important to give data to work with; Otherwise any answer -and therefore none- will satisfy your needs. E.g. : What do you mean by "slicing" exactly (effect on matter, size of your cosmic knife...), and do we have to consider the energy required to make such slice or just the aftermath? You see, no cutting-edge worldbuilding data , just the bare minimal :).

Comment: Also, how much time does it take to slice a planet? All that slicing energy has to go somewhere and if it takes enough time, that energy will impact life all around the planet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three possible scenarios here, with some gray area between them.

### Cut cleanly in half, the parts sent flying in opposite directions

In this case, not by any stretch of the imagination could they support life. The existing crust would collapse like a dying spider, and the magma would flood the edges. Air would be dispersed around the point of separation and never be recovered.

### Brief separation, then rejoining

By "brief", I'm talking about no more than a few minutes. The separation strength just needs to be enough to counteract the mutual gravitational pull of the two halves. The crust would contract around the separation, and the magma would bulge out in the middle, squeezed by gravity. When the two parts rejoined, the magma would splatter in all directions when the two halves met again. The oceans would boil. Guaranteed extinction event for almost all life. Microbes could survive.

### No actual separation, but a loss of all Van der Waals forces along the split line

This one presumes that no force is applied to push the two halves apart. In any area where the tectonic plates were shifting (i.e., any land mass), there would be massive earthquakes as the tension was suddenly released. Tsunamis would wash civilization off of most costal areas. Volcanos would appear all along the fault line, spewing ash into the atmosphere, blocking out the sun.

The atmosphere wouldn't notice this. Life would survive, but the people might not.

### Bonus scenario: Supermassive space laser

Something pumps enough energy into the planet to vaporize the rock along a bisection line. This could be considered equivalent to the "brief separation" scenario above. The difference being that the passing of the laser would induce a wave form to further break up the crust.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not immediately.

After the split the two halves will merge again, unless the split has given each half escape velocity, and the merge will release a huge amount of heat, turning the planet in a sea of molten rock.

Only after cooling down the planet might become again available for life to develop and thrive.

Comment: I don’t think that much energy would be released, depending on how thick the planet is sliced it might barely be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep atmosphere - yes, although it's composition would change significantly. If there was free oxygen, it would likely be gone in the process.

Keep life - no, as @L.Dutch said, the halves would turn into seas of molten rock which even microbial life would be unlikely to survive.

Answer (score 1):

With the amount of energy it would take to split a planet I can't imagine anything left alive.  As for the atmosphere you might keep some of it depending on the make of the atmosphere.